# 2011 iMac kernel panic

Tags: macos, imac, kernel-panic

My iMac keeps shutting down approximately every 3 hours. I added 8GB RAM about a month ago. i also upgraded the firmware.

> BSD process name corresponding to current thread: ReportCrash

```
    Interval Since Last Panic Report:  57898 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          4
Anonymous UUID:                    681A3C63-2108-445E-BF94-C699A7C61BB4

Fri Mar 21 10:51:25 2014
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80002c4794): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80002ab8ae, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000000011bb26aec, CR3: 0x0000000086ef000d, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0x934c0395a0fac321, RBX: 0xfffffe801887ce60, RCX: 0x5557eebe77df5d36, RDX: 0xffffff801d7efd90
RSP: 0xffffff81605d3c20, RBP: 0xffffff81605d3cb0, RSI: 0x0000000100c28000, RDI: 0xffffff801d7efd90
R8:  0xffffff80008bee08, R9:  0xffffff80008bee10, R10: 0xfffffe80543f2800, R11: 0x00080000002ca7f1
R12: 0xfffffe8000000000, R13: 0x0000000100d00000, R14: 0x00000000002f1473, R15: 0x000000000000040a
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff80002ab8ae, CS: 0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
CR2: 0x000000011bb26aec, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Faulting CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81605d38d0 : 0xffffff8000220792 
0xffffff81605d3950 : 0xffffff80002c4794 
0xffffff81605d3b00 : 0xffffff80002da55d 
0xffffff81605d3b20 : 0xffffff80002ab8ae 
0xffffff81605d3cb0 : 0xffffff80002abeca 
0xffffff81605d3cf0 : 0xffffff8000273c46 
0xffffff81605d3de0 : 0xffffff8000274a3a 
0xffffff81605d3e10 : 0xffffff8000237919 
0xffffff81605d3e50 : 0xffffff8000544d49 
0xffffff81605d3ea0 : 0xffffff8000551d18 
0xffffff81605d3f10 : 0xffffff8000553755 
0xffffff81605d3f50 : 0xffffff800021e143 
0xffffff81605d3f90 : 0xffffff80002c3d3a 
0xffffff81605d3fb0 : 0xffffff80002da52c 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: ReportCrash

Mac OS version:
11G63b

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:25:48 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FF3BB088-60A4-349C-92EA-CA649C698CE5
System model name: iMac12,2 (Mac-942B59F58194171B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11113416075054
last loaded kext at 3643266274545: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs  9.8.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8104f000, size 356352)
last unloaded kext at 238066755629: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f80aab000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 9.8.1
com.apple.nke.asp_tcp   6.0.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.9
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.75
com.apple.kext.ATIFramebuffer   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.8f17
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    5.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.2.3
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.ATIRadeonX3000    7.3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   7.3.2
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  312
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.1.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 33
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros40  505.67.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.4b8
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 195.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   3.2.30
com.apple.security.quarantine   1.4
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   195.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   80.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.3d10
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 5.0.0d8
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.6fc18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.2.5a5
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.2.5a5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.1.1d6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.1.33
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSource  1.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.kext.ATI6000Controller    7.3.2
com.apple.kext.ATISupport   7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    7.3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    160.7
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   160.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 4.0.8f17
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.8f17
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.4.8
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   420.3
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.1b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  177.11
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 331.7
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.7.2
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.18
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
Model: iMac12,2, BootROM IM121.0047.B1F, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 12 GB, SMC 1.72f2
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6770M, AMD Radeon HD 6770M, PCIe, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424353302D444A2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424353302D444A2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3130322E413030472020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x830B, 0x4E54344743363442384847304E532D444920
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x9A), Atheros 9380: 4.0.67.5-P2P
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Network Service: FireWire, FireWire, fw0
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST31000528AS, 1 TB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5690H
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 3
USB Device: Officejet 6200 series, 0x03f0  (Hewlett Packard), 0x4b11, 0xfa130000 / 6
USB Device: USB Receiver, 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.), 0xc52b, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8215, 0xfa111000 / 7
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x850b, 0xfa200000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0xfd130000 / 5
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x024f, 0xfd132000 / 6
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd120000 / 4
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader, apple_vendor_id, 0x8403, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Comment: It is your com.apple.driver.AirPort.Atheros, do you have sharing or remote control enabled?

Comment: yeah, the sharing is enabled, but not the remote

Comment: Please specify, shut down as OFF, or sleep mode.

Comment: i upgraded the firmware and airport seems to be gone, but it still kept shutting off with a different error report

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps that new RAM is faulty. Even though the RAM passes the power-on self test (POST) It could still be the root cause of the Kernel Panics. Have you tried taking it out?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! 
This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.